# How to center a span inside a TD?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with a certain tag, grabbed from an external source. This code you will see is taken from another website, and you could also see a date (ex. 15 Juli Måndag) There is dates all over the page, how could I center them with just CSS? Tried with absolute positioning, which leads to have all dates over each other.

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jackbillstrom/sMysu/)

My html:

```
    <div id="header">
    <div class="schema">
        <h1>Schema</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="back"><a id="back" href="index.html"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div class="content" style="margin-top:0px;">
        <div class="article" style="text-align:center;">
            <!-- Här skrivs det ut en massa saker -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
$(window).load(function () { //Fade
    $("#status").fadeOut();
    $("#preloader").delay(350).fadeOut("slow");
})
grabShedule();

function grabShedule() {
    var url = "http://1life.se/scraper/Schedule.php"; //URL
    $.getJSON(url, function (response) {
        var html = response.scraped[0].html; //Answer
        $('.article').append(html); //Answer is appended to .article
    });
}
```

Check out my fiddle, I don't know how to approach this problem...

**How I want it:**
[image: Final]

Comment: you don't have any spans in your code... only divs

Comment: My spans are generated from my JS. Grabbed from an external source...

Comment: What spans? What are you trying to center?

Comment: Don't size your colums and text-align: center;

Comment: @dievardump Styling is inside the grabbed HTML-tags :/

Comment: @Jack so see my answer. You'll have to manipulate the DOM elements after appending the HTML.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can solve it with CSS , see here: http://jsfiddle.net/sMysu/6/ 
It is tricky workaround , but it works:

```
td[valign="top"] {
    display: block;
}

td[valign="top"][style="width: 15%"] {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

If the span is dynamically generated inside the `td`, I suggest you to make it as `display:block;` and align it at the center with `margin:0 auto;`

For Instance,

```
td span{display:block; text-align:center; margin:0 auto;}
```

Comment: Your image and the fiddle both look the same. - @Jack

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATES:**

After a deep analysis, I think I got a simple solution for this.

```
.divider + table>tbody>tr>td:first-child{
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
}
```

From your code, you have a empty div `.divider` before all table.  So using CSS navigation it works.

Check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sMysu/12/)

Comment: You may have misunderstood. I will update my question with a image on how I want it.

Comment: @DKM Vertical, check the added image.

Comment: @Jack can you try using `tr td:first-child{
    position: absolute;
    left:50%
}`

Comment: @user1671639 Tried that in my fiddle, didn't help

Comment: @Jack I'hv updated my answer.  Would like you to give a try and share your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `vertical-align:middle`  to that `TD` where you are showing dates. Will not be in you markup though as you are getting it from another site, so use this as CSS.

```
td{
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sMysu/4/)

Answer (score 2):

try using `text-align: center` in your css

Answer (score 1):

To just align the texts in the specified area in the middle use the following:

```
.article table {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the HTML you get:

```
var html = response.scraped[0].html,
    article = $('.article'); //Svaret
article .append(html); //Svaret skrivs ut i .article
$('table table td', article).each(function () {
    var width = this.style.width;
    if (width == '85%') {
        width = '';
    } else {
        width = '150px';
    }
    this.style.width = width;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sMysu/10/

You also can do it by removing all the width ( so just `$('table table td', article).css('width', '')` instead of the .each loop), and set the width of `table table tr td:first-child` to `150px` in your css

http://jsfiddle.net/sMysu/9/